# Does "max resolution" mean one display or all displays?

Tags: integrated-graphics, intel-graphics

I have a Intel i5 and some problems with my screen. Many times during the day I get this lag so typing or moving windows around is very slow. I'm running two Dell 2560x1440 screens of the two DisplayPorts onboard the motherboard.

I've looked at the specification for the Intel HD 4600 which I have and it states that the Max resolution is "DisplayPort*/HDMI- 3840x2160@ 60Hz". It's okey if its per port, but if its the total supported resolution I understand the drop in performance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it's the maximum resolution per port.
The reason for the sluggishness might be because you're putting too much strain on the display card/processor. I don't suppose it's a laptop. If it is, then check if it is running in High performance mode as opposed to balanced or power saver.

Usually, there are power management and performance settings with the video card. Try adjusting that and see if you see improvement. Most video cards including the in-built ones have 3 modes: **High Performance, Balanced and High Quality** and usually, it's at **Balanced** by default.